# Entity Framework 6: Issues with updating relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on a REST API using ASP.NET Web API 2, and Entity Framework 6 Code First.

## Scenario

I will try to cut it down as much as possible, using the example entities **Product** and **Category**.

```
// "Root" type.
// /api/products
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // We are not exposing foreign key,
    // we want to update the Picture while updating the Product.
    public virtual Picture PrimaryPicture { get; set; }

    // Pictures collection should also update
    // while Product is being updated.
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    // We don't want the entire Category object returned,
    // but we do want an ID so we can always look it up whenever.
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

// Note how all references are expressed as DTO's. I use AutoMapper for this.
// This is what the Web API returns.

public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // PrimaryPicture is returned in Product response,
    // so should also be updatable from same API.
    public PictureDto PrimaryPicture { get; set; }

    // Pictures are returned in Product response,
    // so should also be updatable from same API.
    public ICollection<PictureDto> Pictures { get; set; }

    // Note we only have the category ID in the DTO
    // - hence, that's all we get from the API.
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}


// Root type
// /api/categories
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDto
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // We don't want all products when we query for categories.
}

// Not a root type.
public class Picture
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class PictureDto
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

My API controllers accept DTO types, and return DTO types. They use AutoMapper to map from DTO types to the actual entities used by EF. This works great, however...

The problem is, when I issue an Update (`PUT /api/products/1`) with enough info to map it to the corresponding DTO, the fields not exposed by the DTO will be null.

Example: See the Product entity. It has `PrimaryPicture` and `Pictures`, so has the DTO. The DTO does **not** have the `Category`, so when being mapped to an entity, the `Category` is null, but the `CategoryId` is what it is supposed to be.

This is what happens in Update:

- API controller maps from Dto to entity.
- My repository fetches the entity to update from the database, and applies the updated values (from first step) using **AutoMapper** onto the entity fetched from the DB, which will mark it as dirty in EF. Good.
- `SaveChanges();`

When Entity Framework tries to save the Product entity, it will see that Category is null, but CategoryId has a non-zero value, indicating that there is a relationship, and then hell breaks loose (exception time!).

I worked around that issue by using `DbContext.Entry(product).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedProduct)` instead of AutoMapper in step 2, but then it would not map changes in the Pictures collection, or the PrimaryPicture because SetValues only works on scalar properties, not navigational.

I am trying to stay as generic as possible, is it possible to do this without having to manually update related objects for each entity type we have?

Is there any specific configuration for EF that I am missing?

Comment: At some point, you'll figure out that EF is costing you time.  It'll be even worse in production.

Comment: @Andomar Wrong. I figured that out already. ;)

Comment: @Andomar Would you happen to know if NHibernate is any better at this?

Comment: From what I hear, nHibernate is like EF with the same sort of problems.  I think StackOverflow uses a good ORM, called [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: @Andomar I'd prefer the luxury of not writing SQL :)

Comment: The core problem is that you're using the same 'read' DTO as 'write' DTO as well.

Comment: @haim770 How would I go about it then?

Comment: Something like: `public class UpdateableProductDTO : IMappableTo<Product>` that contains only the 'Updatable' fields. and the `IMappableTo<T>` interface requires something like `public T Map()` to return the mapped Entity. I believe you can make `AutoMapper` call this (manual/custom) method in case it encounters an `IMappableTo<>` type.

Comment: My API clients only have the DTO's to work with, you can't write more info than you can read, so I don't see how this would work? Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: You can't write more info than you can read, but sometimes you want to write *less* (exclude `Category` in your case). anyway, you're saying you already tied to the existing DTO. what is the exact Exception thrown by EF?

Comment: @haim770 ``“The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable”``, and it makes sense - I described this in the question I believe,

Comment: I assume `AutoMapper` internally does: `entity.CategoryId = dto.CategoryId;` but not `entity.Category = null;` as well (which does work fine for me). What if you put a break-point after `AutoMapper` finishes the mapping and change `entity.Category = null;` then continue with `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @haim770 The problem is that automapper **does** set entity.Category = dto.Category (and dto.Category is null). :)